# font_formats does not seem to be working in Tiny 6

Tags: fonts

I am trying to add the Calibri font to TinyMCE 6, but no matter what I set font_formats to, it seems to only display the system defaults. Is there something additional I need to do? Below is my font_formats line from  tinymce.init({...

font_formats: "Arial=arial,Calibri=calibri, helvetica,sans-serif; Arial Black=arial black,avant garde; Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino; Helvetica=helvetica; Times New Roman=times new roman,times;",

Thank you,
Mark

I tried various forms of the above and it seems to always default to the system defaults